# MongoDB python connection

Tags: python, mongodb

I just upgraded my mongoDB subscription and suddenly I get this error everytime I try to connect:
****-shard-00-02.dlu0y.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for '****-shard-00-02.dlu0y.mongodb.net

Does anyone know what is the problem? It worked perfectly fine before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share the code you use to connect?

Comment: Yes I try to fetch data from one of my collection within my database. 
connection_one = 'mongodb+srv://***:****@****.dlu0y.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_one)
then I get this error above. however it does work for me in AWS., and this all happend suddenly when I upgraded my subscription with mongoDB to a paying subscription